# clicking outside of datepickerdialog sets date

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, android-datepicker

When I click out of the `Date Picker Dialog`, it sets the date. Any idea how could I resolve this behavior?

```
click out of dialog : sets date

click on set date : sets date twice

click on cancel : cancels date and then sets it back.
```

Is this a bug?